# Odd, Even combinations and Number of Integers for Each

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers

This is probably a silly question, but, for integers...

$even$ x $even$ = $even$
$even$ x $odd$ = $even$
$odd$ x $even$ = $even$
$odd$ x $odd$ = $odd$

There are 3 times as many combinations that form even numbers than odd numbers, so why aren't there more odd numbers than even ones?

I know the truth can be seen by examining an integer number line, but I want to know why the above argument fails.

Comment: $0$ times anything is $0$; why aren’t there more zeroes than other numbers ?

Comment: Taking it a step further... letting $e$ be even and $o$ be odd, we have $e\times e\times e = e,~e\times e\times o = e, e\times o\times e = e,\dots, o\times o\times e = e,~o\times o\times o = o$... so what is special about "three times as many" rather than "seven times as many"?

Comment: Perhaps you should consider addition?

Comment: Now... it seems to me that your argument is that "*Look here, if I consider $\Bbb N\times \Bbb N$ and I look at a finite square in it of the form $\{0,1,2,\dots,n\}\times \{0,1,2,\dots,n\}$ and I associate with each point a number which is the product of their coordinates, the limit of the ratio of these who result in an odd number is $\frac{1}{4}$*" but this does two things wrong.  First, the interpretation of the grid points as the product of their coordinates is not a bijection with the natural numbers, it is not injective.  You have $36 = 36\times 1 = 18\times 2 = 9\times 4 = \dots$

Comment: Next, even if it were in bijection, it is a rearrangement of sorts and rearrangements of things like this do not necessarily preserve relative density.  I could have rearranged the numbers on the number line: $1,5,2,10,3,15,4,20,6,25,7,30,8,35,9,40,11,45,\dots$ where the even positions are occupied by increasing multiples of five and odd positions are occupied by increasing non-multiples of five.  The relative density of multiples of five in the above rearrangement is $\frac{1}{2}$ despite the relative density normally being $\frac{1}{5}$

Comment: Now... the answer of $\frac{1}{4}$ as the limit of the relative density of points in the square grid whose product of coordinates is odd is a fine answer for *that* question, but do not confuse that question with the question of the relative density of odd numbers in the natural numbers as commonly portrayed in their usual order.  Those are both different questions.

Comment: You can flip the observation on its head if you introduce the concept of "evener." A product is "evener" than its multiplicands if it contains more factors of $2$ than either multiplicand. Starting with the same odd-even choices, you find only in the even x even case is the product "evener," a three to one bias in the other direction.

Comment: It was a noob question folks, can we keep any answers simple and intuitive please?

Comment: In what way is what we have written not simple or intuitive?  You are clearly talking about relative density, whether you realize it or not.  In order to discuss relative density, you must understand what it is.  Further, in order to discuss "size comparisons" of one possibly infinite set to another you must understand what it means to be "bigger" or "smaller" of a set.  If you aren't ready to stop and think about these definitions then you aren't ready for the answer however easy it is.

Comment: Compare your argument to the following:  We have a school with an equal number of boys and girls.  Everyone participates in at least one club but some people may choose to participate in more.  The girls in a show of force decide to all be in every club but the boys are lazy and only participate in one each.  We show a yearbook with photos of the various clubs to someone unfamiliar with our school.  They say, "wow, look at all of the girls in the school... based on these photos they must outnumber the boys at least a hundred to one!" ignoring that certain girls appeared in multiple photos.

Comment: @JMoravitz Well for an amateur maths enthusiast terms like "bijection" and even "relative" density (as a specific mathematical concept) are a bit daunting. Have you read any books by W.W. Sawyer? I was hoping for something along the lines of this: http://www.marco-learningsystems.com/pages/sawyer/Vision_in_Elementary_Mathematics.pdf

Comment: @JMoravitz Your school illustration is very helpful.

Comment: Using lay terms... the idea of a bijection here for our grid of products is "everything appeared once."  It is not a bijection if "some things don't appear" or if "some things appeared more than once" like how some girls appeared in our photos more than once and so threw our estimation off of how many girls there were.  Here, some numbers in our grid are appearing more than once, throwing our estimation off.

Comment: As for relative density and the order in which things are listed... the entire idea is that since these sets are infinite we can't look at the entirety of the sets all at once to compare sizes like we could if they were finite.  In order to circumvent this, we are only then allowed to look at a finite quantity of terms at a time, and we try to do this in a convenient and consistent way.  Ideally, this would be done by looking at the numbers if they were listed in strictly increasing order for consistency's sake.  Looking at them in any other order can also throw things off.

Comment: Interesting way of looking at composition of numbers and a good question. Let's see my answer is intuitive enough.

Answer (score 0):

We can make this even more "surprising"

Every positive integer $N$ can be uniquely written as $$N=2^n\cdot m$$ with non-negative integer $n$ and odd $m$. Only if $n=0$, $N$ is odd, so "almost all" numbers should be even.

What is the catch ?

If we get to a fixed limit (instead of considering all positive integers), we will se that the upper bound for $m$ gets smaller with increasng $n$, so the number of even numbers is not larger (at least if the limit is even, otherwise we have one more odd number).

For infinite sets this leads to counterintuitive facts as "there are as many posite integers than numbers of the form $2^n$" with positive integer $n$" although very few positive integers are a power of $2$.

The even numbers are a proper subset of the positive integers, so in some sense there are "as many positive integers as even numbers". We only get to the correct fraction $\frac{1}{2}$, if we consider finite cases and increase the limit.

"Hilbert's hotel" might be a good introduction to get a feeling for this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

What you have observed is correct, but it is not about the Natural numbers, it is about product of natural numbers with themselves.

multiplying ${1,2,3,4,5,6,7,\cdots}$  with itself we get the following :

$$\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & \cdots\\
 2 & 4 & 6 & 8 & 10 & 12 & 14 & \cdots\\
 3 & 6 & 9 & 12 & 15 & 18 & 21 & \cdots\\
 4 & 8 & 12 & 16 & 20 & 24 & 26 & \cdots\\
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The ratio of odd to even for above should be 1 to 3 and that is based on your observation of result of multiplication of evens and odds.

This seems to be the intuitive way of interpreting your observation.

Answer (score 0):

It's a property of multiplication. Addition does not have this special ordering. To get deeper into what happens we should look at a very simple example with squares.

Here we have two numbers; one odd number = $3$ and one even number = $2$. It does not really matter what numbers we choose, as long as its one even and one odd number. Setup some squares to see whats going on:

[image]

Here we've just added the same odd number to itself many times, and do the same thing to the even number. Take a look at what happens. The even number never changes to even. But the odd number changes each time. To conclude so far; for the odd case it looks like a discrete switch that turns odd to even and even to odd. For the even case, this switch is never touched. This was the most discrete example I could think of.

Im sure one can analyse this and find out deeper things.